# Unable to remove BackButton in Navigation controller using Storyboard in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, back-button

I am new to iOS,

I am developing shopping App for IPhone using Storyboard,

Here is the snapshot of my App,
[image]
`TabBarController` contains 4 Tab with `NavigationController`

When i open `Tab1`(let say `class1`) it contains `TableView`, onclick of tableview it will take me to `Detail page` with title and back button on `NavigationBar` (I am adding title and back button programatically in `ViewWillAppear method`) after this when i hit back button i navigates to previous page properly, this is working fine..

My problem is When i open `Tab1`(i.e class1) and when i navigates to `Detail page` after selecting a row in tableview, in a `Detail page`, `BackBtn` and title will be added in `NavigationBar` bcoz `ViewWillAppear method` will be called, and when i hit `Tab2` before hitting Backbtn, i am navigates to class of `Tab2` and thn when i comes back to `Tab1` and  now i clicks on back button i am navigating to previous page of my `Tab1 class` (i.e `class1`) but on `class1`  back Button and title of `Detail page` is there on my `class1` i am unable to hide it...

You can see in the 2nd image `BackBtn` and `Title` is there in `Class1`.. 
[image]
What's the problem ?

Comment: I presumed you are pushing tab batr controller rather you have to present or add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[btnBack setHidden:YES]` in `viewWillDisapper:` method in Detail page

Comment: nice ans dude it works... i am able to hide back button but how to hide title ?

Comment: but i think you should use setBackBarButtonItem: for adding your custom back button

Comment: i am adding label to UinavigationBar `navLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70,7,180,30)];
    navLabel.text = strTitle;
    navLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f];
    navLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    navLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    navLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [[self.navigationController navigationBar] addSubview:navLabel];`same way i am hiding label.. work is done.. thanx for the help

Comment: same, if you are doing this in viewWillAppear method of detail page, then [navLabel setHidden:YES]; or [navLabel removeFromSuperview]; in viewWillDisappear method of detail class. Hope this helps

Answer (score 7):

just hide that backButton in `viewWillAppear:` method of `Class1` like bellow...

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

or

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

**UPDATE:**

if you add custom button to the `UINavigationBar` then just remove that button like bellow...

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

and if you want to remove right bar button then use bellow another code like above...

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

i hope this helpful to you...

Comment: Doesnot solves the problem, i am adding custom button on navigation bar, instead of adding back button. is there any property to hide custom button from navigation bar ?

Comment: what is the name of button?? means just take that button globaly and hide when you want.. just post the code where you add this button on navigationbar

Comment: I am calling this method from `ViewWillappear` code: `-(void)addBack
{
    btnBack =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnBack.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(backClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnBack setFrame:CGRectMake(7, 7, 65, 30)];
    [[self.navigationController navigationBar] addSubview:btnBack];
}`

Comment: oh then just write this line..     [btnBack setHidden:YES]; and also here not call this addBack method again in viewWillAppear..

Comment: I am unable to hide back button of `Previous Page` in `class1` if i write `[btnBack setHidden:YES];` it will hide backbutton of `class1`, i want to hide backbutton of previos page.

Comment: oh then in your that previous page class's viewWillAppear method just write that code try this...

Comment: i tried your suggestion and this thing `[btnBack removeFromSuperview];` but still didnt success..

Comment: try this answer also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276861/how-can-i-dynamically-hide-a-button-from-a-view

Comment: u can do this:                                                    1>In previous page viewWillDisapper u should write                   [btnBack setHidden:YES];                                                                                                                    2>set btnback as self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem or self.navigationItem. rightBarButtonItem and in previous page's viewWillDisapper make self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil and self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=nil

Comment: yes its also right but now i understand that what is the problem.. i just think that its problem with subview of navigationbar only but here also lable and also button which is the object of that class only so here required to do something with that in same class so  .. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

Will give you which item you are currently selecting.

You can work around if you cant fix it by popping to root view controller and pushing it again. And make sure you are not adding a subview in place of pushing a view controller.